# Which is the most efficient on iOS - CSS3 or jQuery animations?

Tags: jquery, ios, css

Do iOS devices render the CSS3 animations/transforms/transitions more smoothly than if I were to use jQuery to do the same animation?

Comment: Why don't you set up a page and test this?

Comment: I never use jQuery animations on iOS - only webkit. I did notice that webkit was smoother on iOS 4 than it is on iOS 5, though - both on older iPad 1s and newer iPad 2s.

Comment: I think the title is a better question than the one proposed - "Is it standard practice"

Comment: thank you all for your fast responses.  I like the new title. That's what i meant to ask :) @Matt H  I wonder why webkit isn't as smooth in iOS5.

Comment: Man, I sure wish I knew! I have a hybrid app that has up to 20 swirling and moving photos. Smooth as silk in iOS 4. Starts off smooth in iOS 5, then degrades over time, becoming jerky.

Comment: @user1121622 - upvotes are a good way to thank people that help you on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS3 transitions are massively faster on iOS and should be used whenever possible in preference to the old way of doing things.

If you combine transitions with transforms then you get the benefit that things are hardware accelerated, meaning that animations are very fluid, especially when many are happening at once.

Of course, you'll need to test it to see, but it's fairly easy to write a function that allows you to abstract this away. Here's one I wrote a while back - not the greatest, but it's an easy way to start off: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/legacy/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can be very slow on iOS, and it would probably use CSS3 anyway after it detected the brower's capabilities. jQuery is not necessarily fast, just cross-browser compatible. Writing HTML, CSS, and JavaScript targeted to a browser will always be faster.

Comment: Also note that CSS animations are hardware accelerated on iOS, jQuery animations are not.